# Как найти самую длинную последовательность пересекающихся событий?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть табличка `Events` со следующими полями:

- Id
- CreationDate
- DeletionDate
- PostId
- Name

Для одного `PostId` может быть произвольное количество записей в таблице `Events`. Мне необходимо подсчитать самую длинную последовательность событий пересекающихся во времени для каждого `PostId`. Два события пересекаются во времени, если у них совпадает `PostId` и  `CreationDate` одного события попадает в интервал между `CreationDate` и `DeletionDate` другого.

Подскажите, как реализовать подсчет наибольшей последовательности для произвольного количества событий?

Comment: Вот так хочется написать где ваши попытки.

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД и её версию. Вообще - эвент разворачивается в точки времени (вход - плюс 1, выход - минус 1), всё это сортируется по времени и считается сумма с накоплением. Там, где пачка эвентов разрывается, сумма будет нулевой.

Comment: @Akina Это одна из последний версий MS SQL Server. Вроде бы добил реализацию, сейчас проверяю (как всегда, думаешь полдня, но как только вопрос задашь, сразу идея верная в голову приходит). Буду очень рад если вы сможете показать пример реализации. Свою выложу сразу после проверки.

Comment: Выложите тестовый набор - CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (5-10 записей) + эталонный ответ. Или ссылку на fiddle.

Comment: @AzizUmarov Хорошо хоть не закрыли вопрос...

Comment: Чёрт, невнимательно прочитал задачу... по сабжу думал, что (1..4 + 3..7 + 6..9) - это три, а на самом деле по тексту, оказывается, два...

Comment: @Akina Да, совершенно верно, это два интервала длинной два.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT t1.PostId, 
                     COUNT(t2.PostId) cnt, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.PostId ORDER BY COUNT(t2.PostId) DESC) rn
              FROM Events t1
              JOIN Events t2 ON t1.PostId = t2.PostId
                            AND t2.CreationDate BETWEEN t1.CreationDate AND t1.DeletionDate
              GROUP BY t1.PostId, t1.CreationDate )
SELECT PostId, cnt MaxCnt
FROM cte           
WHERE rn = 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=20b02dcf4070488801bcca4b742ea9c7)

Answer (score 2):

У меня получился такой запрос

```
SELECT 
  PostId,
  MAX(Cnt) MaxCnt
FROM 
( 
  SELECT 
    e1.PostId,
    COUNT(IIF(e2.CreationDate BETWEEN e1.CreationDate AND e1.DeletionDate, 1, NULL)) Cnt
  FROM Events e1
    INNER JOIN Events e2 ON e2.PostId = e1.PostId
  GROUP BY
    e1.PostId, e1.CreationDate, e1.DeletionDate
) AS X
GROUP BY 
  PostId
```

Основаня идея:

- Мы бежим по табличке `Events`  (`e1`)
- Для каждой записи `e1` находим совпадающие с ней по `PostId` записи в той же табличке `Events` (`e2`).
- С помочью `BETWEEN` проверяем совпадение интервала.
- Если интервал совпадает, увеличиваем счетчик.
- На выходи имеем все интервалы для каждого `PostId`.
- Остается сгруппировать и найти максимальное значение.

Comment: Если убрать из условий связывания `e2.Id != e1.Id`, то и  связывание можно делать INNER (уж с собой-то любая запись пересечётся), и `+ 1` к COUNT не потребуется.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, вы правы! Поправил.